# Why do BT router firewall rules keep resetting?

Tags: router, firewall, port-forwarding, broadband

A large number of our customers have routers supplied by BT when they order business broadband.  When the routers are installed, we configure the firewall to allow our EPOS system to communicate between shops.

About every two weeks, customers call us complaining that the system is not communicating.  After connecting to there computer we find that the firewall has been reset to **Maximum Protection** and the firewall rules have been deleted.

What could be causing this problem?  Is this caused by automatic firmware updates?

Comment: Do you by chance have the model number of the routers?

Comment: I just checked one of the routers and it is a BT2700HGV

Comment: That model does indeed do automatic updates, per the tech specs: "Automatic, remote software upgrades via the secure TR-069 remote management standard to ensure the latest features and services are available." I am not sure if this would modify the firewall though. It also has "Web-based remote gateway technician view and remote
management" so it is always possible for a script to run periodically and ensure that all routers are configured to BT specs. I know when I worked for an ISP we had scripts that ran to ensure certain config settings were set in our routers.

Comment: Does their arrangement with BT say they manage the routers? Or does BT? If the former, you have to arrange the firewall changes with BT, you can't make them yourself. If the latter, I'd say BT is violating the agreements and managing the routers anyway.